# How many bound items can you have?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

How many bound items can you have?

By "bound" I am referring to features which state something like "you receive [some item] as a bonded object".

For example, the wizard’s bonded item option, the magus’s blackblade archetype which is a bound weapon, or ioun bound arcane discovery.

Comment: I, what? Are you sure you're talking about pathfinder 1e? If so, what exactly are you referring to? Can you provide links to the relevant content you're asking about?

Comment: I'm also unfamiliar with the concept of item "binding"

Comment: 99% of the magic items work by wearing.

Comment: @Trish unsure if that's aimed at the OP or my comment, so I figured I may as well explain myself. I'm unsure if the OP is talking about binding as in wearing a magic item, or binding as in something like a wizard's bonded item (my first thought), or occultist implements. It could even be some 3rd party class that binds objects or something about having ropes tied around you to bind you to an object (unlikely but still possible). Given how there's nothing to go off of, I believe this question needs more details before it's reopened.

Comment: It was a comment about how PF1 handled magic items: most of them just demand you to be in possession of them and use them, at times for a specified time.

Comment: Stuff like the wizard’s bonded item option- or the magus’s blackblade archtype witch is a bound weapon, or ioun bound arcane discovery - basically anything with the text “you gain a <item> as a bonded object” in the feature

Comment: @Pacattack I've cleaned up your question and also removed the second part of it. I believe that constitutes a second question best asked as its own separate question.

Comment: Can you clarify if you believe there to be a limit on the number of 'bonded' items? Or, are you seeking an optimization answer that strives for a build that has the most number of 'bonded' items over some number of levels?

Comment: Now I'm curious as to how many bonded items you could realistically build for a level 20 character with expected money.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I can find, there is no rules text about bound items, just that you only get one from each class feature that gives you one, such as the features described in the question. There are no other rules about bound objects aside from what is explicitly described in those class features.

Answer (score 2):

There is no upper limit.

Some specific items limit you to an amount of its type (like "only 1 black blade"), but you can have as many objects as you want.

A wizard multiclassed with arcane sorcerer can select 'bonded object' on both, getting 2 objects. they need to be separate ones (not the same amulet), and they ant cross class (the wizards ring doesn't give you an extra sorcerer spell)